# How to restore Redshift cluster from another AWS Account's snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cli, snapshot

I want restore a Redshift cluster from another account's snapshot.

First, I took a manual snapshot of in account A. Then I successfully shared this snapshot to account B. So now I want to restore a new cluster from that snapshot in account B.

I tried this command

> aws redshift restore-from-cluster-snapshot --node-type ds2.8xlarge --number-of-nodes 5 --snapshot-identifier snap-a-id --cluster-identifier cluster-b

But I'm getting

> An error occurred (ClusterSnapshotNotFound) when calling the RestoreFromClusterSnapshot operation: Snapshot not found: snap-a-id

I am able to see `snap-a-id` on my AWS console.

Comment: When you run CLI, do you specify AWS region? If you do not and snapshot is not in your default region, then the error is expected.

Comment: Both accounts are on the same region. I can run describe-cluster-snapshots command, and I'm getting the description of the snapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [restore-from-cluster-snapshot — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/restore-from-cluster-snapshot.html):

> `--owner-account` (string)
>
> The AWS customer account used to create or copy the snapshot. Required if you are restoring a snapshot you do not own, optional if you own the snapshot.